# How to find descendant elements up to a certain depth in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to search for a XML node, but limiting the search to a certain depth? What is the expression for that?

For example, I want to find all `article` tags, but exclude nested article tags, so only id 1 and 2.

```
<div id="timeline">
...
    <article id="1"> </article>
    <article id="2">
       ...
       <article id=3> </article>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer help?  If so, please accept.  If not, please let me know how I can address any remaining concerns.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
//article[not(ancestor::article)]
```

will select all `article` elements that have no `article` ancestors, so for your example XML, it will only select `article` elements with `id` attribute values of `1` or `2`.

To more generally limit selection based upon depth (as is asked in your question's title), the number of ancestors can be counted:

- `//article[count(ancestor::article) < 3]` for those `article` elements with less than three `article` ancestors.
- `//article[count(ancestor::*) < 3]` for those `article` elements with less than three ancestors of any type.
- `//*[count(ancestor::*) < 3]` for any elements with less than three ancestors.